# ubuntu server 20.04 run on raspberry CM4 (wifi chip inside) , wifi interface not found

Tags: raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 server in raspberry P4B and CM4(with wifi), CM4 can't find wifi interface but P4B can find wlan0. what's the difference between them?
And some kind guys can tell me how to fix wifi problem on CM4.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure your CM4 is a model with a wifi interface?

Comment: I found that Ubuntu 20.04 didn't have very good support for CM4 but its much improved in 20.10.

Comment: CM4/Raspberry PI support is even more improved in 21.04 which is released in April.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem.  I can confirm that 20.10 recognizes the interface wlan0, and can connect to a wireless router through wlan0